# How to find the total cost of an Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cost-calculation

How would I find the total cost of an Azure function (including costs incurred by the Azure function on the Azure storage account such as cost of LRS List and Create Container Operations when multiple Azure functions are using the same Azure storage account)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can See functions costs by going to

Cost Management >> Cost Analysis >> View CostByResource >> Sort By ResourceType

[image]

For me, it doesn't give much details, the best option is to have an `App Service Plan` which is applied to the function, where you can get CPU/Memory consumption cost:
This time Select `previews (Sort By ResourceType)`:

[image]

As for the Storage Account cost related to a function, you'll get all details for Storage costs but not specific to functions ( I'd assume you'll use storage account only for functions)

[image]